# UIViewController not released when added to a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc, viewdidunload

Below is reduced bit of code to demonstrate a problem I am a having.

I allocate and init a view controller. The init method is the standard Objective C init, so the view controller isn't doing anything yet. Then I create a navigationController initializing the root with the newly created view controller.
I then release the view controller since the nav has it now and I don't need it.
In the next line nav is released and I would expect that the view controller's dealloc/viewDidUnload would be called. 
Instead they are not. 
If I don't put the sportsViewController on the nav controller, dealloc is called after sportsViewController is released. 
What am I doing wrong?
(BTW I have other similar pieces of code that work correctly)

```
SportsViewController *sportsViewController = [[SportsViewController alloc]  init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sportsViewController];
[sportsViewController release];
[nav release];
```